# Why does this SSIS Conversion Expression syntax the way it is?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm looking at an SSIS package with a `Derived Column` Data Flow Component

When, I open it, I see 1 transformation:

```
Derived COLUMN Name : CLIENT_ID
Derived COLUMN: "REPLACE 'CLIENT_ID'"
EXPRESSION: TRIM(CLIENT_ID) == "" ? (DT_STR,9,1252)NULL(DT_STR,9,1252) : CLIENT_ID
DATA TYPE: string [DT-STR]
LENGTH: 9
PRECISION: 
SCALE: 
CODE PAGE: 1252 (ANSI- LATIN I)
```

I'm trying to understand the SSIS expression and I'm not sure that I understand the syntax.

```
TRIM(CLIENT_ID) == "" ? (DT_STR,9,1252)NULL(DT_STR,9,1252) : CLIENT_ID
```

I believe that the code is reading in the CLIENT_ID field from a flat file and that the field is coming in as a string. The conversion appear to check to see if the value read is all whitespace and if so, converts to a NULL string value, otherwise uses the original `CLIENT_ID` string value.

The syntax of the conversion confused me, perhaps because I am trying to relate it to C# code. I expected the following for the EXPRESSION:

```
TRIM(CLIENT_ID) == "" ? NULL : CLIENT_ID
```

or perhaps

```
TRIM(CLIENT_ID) == "" ? (DT_STR,9,1252)NULL : CLIENT_ID
```

Why is NULL surrounded by *two* conversions: `(DT_STR,9,1252)`?

Comment: this is only happening with `DT_STR` data type if you cast to `DT_WSTR` this expression will work `TRIM(CLIENT_ID) == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,9) : (DT_WSTR,9)CLIENT_ID` ... this is a bit confusing . maybe it is a string encoding issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this mean? LEN(TRIM(Weight)) == 0 ? (DT\_STR,50,1252)NULL(DT\_STR,50,1252) : (DT\_STR,50,1252)Weight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858210/what-does-this-mean-lentrimweight-0-dt-str-50-1252nulldt-str-50-125)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS has a [separate null for each datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/null-ssis-expression).  E.g., `NULL(DT_STR,9,1252)` means a null that is specific to a nine character string on that code page.

As in C#, the first `(DT_STR,9,1252)` is a type cast.  Of course, the cast is not necessary here, since this `NULL` already has the correct data type.

Comment: I Get a syntax expression error when I previously tried TRIM(CLIENT_ID) == "" ? NULL(DT_STR,9,1252) : CLIENT_ID, so it still appears to be necessary to convert the "string NULL" to a string, which is strange.

Comment: I don't know why an additional cast seems to be necessary after the data type of the destination column has already been defined via the null type.